# Cannot connect to MySQL server hosted in docker from external machine

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm setting up a MySQL server inside a Docker container

```
sudo docker run --name test-mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_USER=desktop -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% -d mysql
```

For some reason I can't figure out, an external machine cannot connect to it, no matter what I try.

Here is the content of `my.cnf`

```
root@f9042fc2a105:/# cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf
# Copyright (c) 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
secure-file-priv= NULL

# Custom config should go here
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Here is `docker.cnf`

```
root@f9042fc2a105:/# cat /etc/mysql/conf.d/docker.cnf
[mysqld]
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
```

Here is `mysql.cnf`

```
# Copyright (c) 2015, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
[mysql]
```

Here is the content of the User table

```
mysql> select user, host from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| desktop          | %         |
| root             | %         |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the error I get when connecting from an external machine using [MySQL shell](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/):

```
 MySQL  JS > \connect --mysql root@192.186.1.85
Creating a Classic session to 'root@192.186.1.85'
Please provide the password for 'root@192.186.1.85': ********
MySQL Error 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060
```

The docker host machine has no firewall.

Comment: could you please share results of netstat -n64l, docker ps and docker network ls on host machine

Comment: Just flagged my own question as duplicate. Docker was absolutely fine in my configuration. The culprit was MySQL shell, which should have been switched to `\sql` mode before use.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the firewall rules.
Maybe you have to allow something like:

```
ufw route allow proto tcp from any to any port 3306
```

Did you manage to ping the instance of MySQL on the port 3306?

By the way keep in mind that allowing any is not safe, you should allow only your IP o the one you are trying to connect from.

Comment: As stated in the original post, there is no firewall on the host machine. Moreover, `sudo ufw status` returns `status:inactive`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you have to **activate** and **allow** the port that MySQL is listening to, which is `3306`, due to the port mapping `-p 3306:3306` in your description. And also check if MySQL remote access is enabled or not.

> By default, UFW is set to **deny all incoming connections** and allow all outgoing connections. This means anyone trying to reach your cloud server would not be able to connect, while any application within the server would be able to reach the outside world.

You can read about the default inactive firewall [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121172/what-happens-if-ufw-firewall-is-inactive).

You may try the below steps:

**Step 1**: Setting up the rules **BEFORE** activate your ufw firewall.

```
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow 3306
```

Make sure you allow ssh port too if the host is a remote machine. If anything happens, at least we can ssh to it and find what is happening.

**Step 2**: Activate your firewall

```
sudo ufw enable
```

**Step 3**: Check the host machine's firewall status

```
sudo ufw status
```

It should be somewhat like this

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3306                       ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
3306 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

**Step 4**: Enabling MySQL remote access. By default, MySQL remote access is disabled. Find the `mysqld.cnf` file of your MySQL in the container

```
sudo vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

and add the configuration below

```
#bind-address   = 127.0.0.1 <-- If there is any line like this, comment it out.
bind-address   = 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: As stated in the original post, there is no firewall on the host machine. Moreover, `sudo ufw status` returns `status : inactive`.

Comment: @ArthurAttout As stated in my answer, `status: inactive` doesn't mean that "there is no firewall". It means there is firewall on the host machine, and it is inactive. And I have added a reference link above for describing "what happens if ufw firewall is inactive?".  You can read some for troubleshooting.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121172/what-happens-if-ufw-firewall-is-inactive

Comment: The accepted answer in the question you are linking is simply confirming the reasoning I had : "_Yes to your first answer, it is inactive so all traffic goes through._". I know the machine has no firewall, and your answer mentions configuration for `ufw`. Which is a firewall. And which is disabled, in addition.

Comment: I'm having troubles understanding your reasoning. Do you suggest that `status:inactive` could mean `ufw` is interfering in the process ? What part of the the question you linked makes you think so ?

Comment: `By default, UFW is set to deny all incoming connections.... This means anyone trying to reach your cloud server would not be able to connect.....` <-- This part makes me think this is the reason you can't make a connection from an external machine to the host machine. It is an inbound connection, by default, it should be denied.

Comment: No, this is not what the answer says. OP asked "_if ufw is not enabled which means it's INACTIVE. does it mean it allows anything at all? whatever we want?_". The accepted answer is "_Yes to your first answer, it inactive so all traffic goes through._".

Comment: Oops, my bad. Sorry for taking your time for answering my dump comment. Btw, Have you resolved the problem by switching to `\sql` mode yet? If not, you can try to enabling MySQL remote access. If yes, then I've learned something new.